# React query global error handling avoid multiple toast

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-query

I have a project using React and React query, to fetch an external API.

I used the global error handling described there : https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-error-handling which is great for mostly every errors.

However, when I get error 401 from server (Unauthenticated), for example when my token has been revoked, I use a redirection to login page with a toast to tell the user to re-authenticate. The problem I got, is that on the home page, I got multiple queries fetching at the same time different data, and they all return 401, and when I get redirected I got 3 toast spawning.

How would you avoid this, and only redirect and make one toast spawn ?

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    queryCache: new QueryCache({
      onError: (error) => {
        if (error?.request?.status === 401) {
          removeCookies();
          return toast.info("Please authenticate");
        }
      },
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came up with an easy solution.

react-toastify has a built in way to avoid duplicated toasts by giving  it an id :

```
return toast.info("please authenticate", {
   toastId: 1
});
```

Thank's TkDodo for the track.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to achieve this. The callback runs for every Query, and if multiple of them fail, the callback will be called multiple times.

One way would be to do some deduplication on `toast` level, so that toast with the same message are not rendered.

Or, you could check only for a specific QueryKey and only show the toast for one of them.

Comment: I was thinking about doing something like this, nice to be sure that there is no built in way. I'll post my solution whenever I got time to spend on this !